# What airlines have a habit of checking the weight of carry on luggage at the gate rather than at check in?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, hand-luggage, lufthansa

I fly on Lufthansa occasionally, mainly between Philadelphia and Frankfurt.  I only have a carry on and I know they have a weight limit.  The thing is while they do sometimes check the weight of the bag if I go to the counter to check in they will also sometimes check the weight at the gate, right before the flight boards, so you can't go back through security and put anything too heavy from your bag in your car.  I was wondering if there is a website or anything that had an extensive list of all the airlines and their tendencies to try to screw over passengers like this.  Like is there a website somewhere that says Lufthansa does this occasionally, some other airline does it all the time and is basically their standard practice, and some third airline maybe has no reported instances of this?

Comment: Another situation in which it's different is for travellers to buy things in shops after security.

Comment: With families and groups, it is common to leave cabin baggage outside site of check-in staff, or appearing with more items. @gerrit: shops after checking often have additional allowance (and some people have airport shop bags for such reasons).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi By "outside site" you mean "out of sight"? I had to read your comment a couple of times to get your meaning and am still not sure (why only families and groups?).  I haven't heard of extra allowance for shops but then again I fly rarely and have never bought more than a magazine or food in airport shops.

Comment: @gerrit: yes, "out of sight". Sorry for my English, I should recheck what I write. Family and groups: 1- an other member of group could take care of hand baggages. 2- families moves (children), and it is difficult to take care of baggages (and desk hides a lot). Shops: https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/bagages-cabine-airfrance.htm (I was thinking that it was also on Lufthansa, but it seems I'm wrong). [Note: flag airlines have less strict rules]

Comment: “Screw over passengers” is probably a bit strong here. It’s not like they don’t tell you in advance, and nothing prevents you from weighing your bag yourself to make sure you are within limits. Consider that anytime you fly with more than the allowed weight and they don’t notice it’s just a bonus, and if you feel their allowance is too small, either pay more for a different class of travel which allows more or take your money elsewhere...

Comment: @gerrit, found maybe "Please stow your personal items, such as laptop bags, shopping bags or handbags, under the seat in front of you." (then about jackets), https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/carry-on-baggage  so it seems such items are not considered as normal item

Comment: @jcaron: "screw over" seems appropriate since it's hard to find a rational reason for that. Most airlines either don't control weight at all so it can't be a safety related issue. A normal sized (24x14x9) weighs about 5 kg empty so an 8kg cap makes this basically useless. I had to buy a smaller super-light case and start to carefully control what I'm bring just for LH group. No more presents or gifts for the family. Another LH "screw over" is seat reservation. Recently they wanted to charge $85 for reserving a normal economy seat for a single leg!

Comment: If Lufthansa, which in my experience is true to the German stereotype of being "sticklers," doesn't enforce the policy in a single way, you're unlikely to be pleased with how consistently things are executed on United, say, or Alitalia.

Comment: I usually travel with a pretty heavy rucksack which, however, will always for under the seat in front of me. I have yet to have that rucksack get weighed. However, I also suspect their main problem, if any, is cabin bags that will not fit under the seat.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know of any web-sites with that information. In Australia Jetstar is notorious for using a portable set of scales on a trolley at the gate lounge. It is random, not at every gate lounge and not at every airport but I have seen it in operation several times at Gold Coast and Melbourne. If your carry-on, including any handbags or computer bags, exceeds 7kg you will be charged a high price. I learned the hard way the first time. I was less than 2kg over: $50.00.